# Storing an image in sdcar using Aquery - Android

Tags: android, image, storage, aquery

I am trying to store an image from the net into my emulator's sdcard. However I get an expection more specifically a null object reference.

```
W/AQuery: reporting:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
                                         at testing.theo.androidqueryexample.MainActivity.handfile(MainActivity.java:69)
                                         at testing.theo.androidqueryexample.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:19)
                                         at testing.theo.androidqueryexample.MainActivity$1.callback(MainActivity.java:61)
                                         at testing.theo.androidqueryexample.MainActivity$1.callback(MainActivity.java:56)
                                         at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.callback(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:506)
                                         at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.afterWork(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:1299)
                                         at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.run(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:998)
                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

My code is shown below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

AQuery aq;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    aq = new AQuery(this);

    /*Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setText("new text");
    b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    b.setEnabled(true);*/

    aq.id(R.id.button).clicked(this, "clickhandle");
}

    public void clickhandle(View view){

        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setTitle("Loading Image");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
    aq.id(R.id.button).text("aquery text").backgroundColor(Color.RED).
            textColor(Color.YELLOW).enabled(true);
        //aq.id(R.id.imageView).progress(pd).image("http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/127854802.jpg",true,true,0,0,null,AQuery.FADE_IN);

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myfiles/myimage.jpg");
        if(!f.exists())

        try {
            f.mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        aq.download("http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/127854802.jpg", f, new AjaxCallback<File>(){

                @Override
                public void callback(String url, File object, AjaxStatus status) {
                    super.callback(url, object, status);
                    handfile(object);
                }
            });


    }

        private void handfile(File object) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"got file: " +object.getAbsolutePath().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

Line 69 corresponds to the Toast message inside the handlefile(...) method.

What could be wrong?

I declared the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and INTERNT permissions in the manifest file.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a NPE, check that `object != null`

Comment: I do it as if(!f.exists())...

Comment: For some reason when you call `handfile` the file is null

Comment: I know. The file object I am declaring is not passed to the parameter of the handlefile(...) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I found is that your creating the file `myimage.jpg` inside directory `myfiles` but that directory doesn't exists. Try creating the directory structure before creating the file.

```
File f = new File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myfiles/myimage.jpg");

if(!f.exists())
    try {
        f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); //create missing parents
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I put a breakpoint before File f = new File(Environment.....) and I have this: '/storage/emulated/0/myfiles/myimage.jpg' from the debugger. So I get your point. But I don't know how to create the directory structure, before creating the actual file.

Comment: See my answer, `f.getParentFile().mkdirs()`

Comment: Unfortunately,I have the same problem:(

Comment: @Theo Just put `f.getParentFile().mkdirs()` before `f.createNewFile()`. Please notice this in the answer.